# Suffix for 'likely to do'

Tags: suffixes

What brought this up was `sabotage`, is there a general modifier for a noun (so not necessarily a suffix) to describe someone as about to perform an act of that noun?

So if we did it to `sabotage`, I could call someone *that* and the meaning would be `you're a person likely to commit sabotage`.
But someone who is yet to, not someone who currently practices or has already done *it* (`saboteur`).

The only one I can think of is `-al` for `suicidal`, someone thinking about/considering `suicide`.
Maybe sabotage in particular is difficult, are there any more of these noun-adjective pairs?

Comment: I wanted to use the tag `word-family` for the question ("`A word family is the base form of a word plus its inflected forms and derived forms made from affixes"`) but it doesn't exist and I don't have the rep, anyone wanna create it so this question has more meaningful tags?

Comment: You mean like "sabotagial" or some such?  I don't know of either a specific word for "likely to sabotage" nor do I know of a suffix meaning "likely to".  Probably the best one can do is [-istic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-istic) (*of, relating to, or characteristic of*), but it's not that specific.

Comment: '-ive / -ative / -itive' would be great suffixes for tendency or disposition, but there is no such word as 'saboteurive'.  Or the Latin prefix 'ad' was also once indicative of tendency (shortened to 'a-' in Old French), but again 'asaboteur' doesn't exist.  Still, these are affixes that can indicate tendency (e.g., 'ag-' is an alteration of 'ad-' in the word 'aggressive', which also bears the suffix '-ive').

Comment: I have seen '-bent' used for a similar purpose.

Comment: for which words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sabotagical* is a slang word used to convey the meaning of "having characteristics of sabotage or a saboteur." Otherwise, one would just use that phrase or paraphrase. For example, one would say, "he's likely to sabotage;" "he's often a saboteur;" or "he's sabotag**ing**." Indeed, *-ing* is probably the closest applicable suffix to what you're looking for, but this only applies the qualities of the noun, not the specific meaning of "likely to sabotage." "He's abusing;" "he's loving;" and "he's questioning" are examples with other words. Compare *abusive*, *affectionate*, and *inquisitive*.

*Sabotage-prone* has a similar meaning, but I don't think it conveys intent. Someone who is accident-prone does not intend to commit accidents, for instance. If they did, they wouldn't be accidents.

Comment: Thanks for chucking in a bunch of alternatives. I guess I was asking a bit much for such a specific word to exist, I just hoped it was just a matter of my not knowing it

Comment: @Hashbrown, you're welcome! Don't be afraid to ask a question if you think a word for it probably exists, though. I've seen all sorts of single-word requests that get very specific answers.